# HTML loop PHP without messing with this " over '

Tags: php, html, loops

I have this php code with an html for a loop

```
if($contenido_index === 1 || $contenido_index === "1") {   
                                                   echo "
        <div class='portcontrol'>
            <div class='info_container cssemigrey'>
                <a href='". $contenido_link."'><h2 class='naranja'>". $contenido_titulo."</h2></a>
            </div>

            <div class='wrapimg'>
                <a href='". $contenido_link."'><img alt='Image de ". $contenido_titulo."' src='". $contenido_imagen."'></a>
            </div>
        </div>
";}
```

I dont want to change for example href=" " for this href=' '

Is there any other way to write it so I can paste the normal HTML code that i'm going to use for a loop.

Comment: Take a look at HERDOC or NOWDOC

Comment: Why two checks for $contenido_index?

Comment: Olly Tenerife i'm using wordpress pods pluging to work on it, its safier to do the both checks,

Answer (score 1):

Change `echo "` for `echo '`

That way you won't have to escape double-quote marks in the HTML you are echoing.

Answer (score 1):

Just figure it out from a joomla template...

```
<?php if($contenido_index === 1 || $contenido_index === "1"): ?>
  <div class="portcontrol">
              <div class="info_container cssemigrey">
                    <a href="<?php echo $contenido_link; ?>"><h2 class='naranja'>"<?php echo $contenido_titulo; ?></h2></a>
                </div>

                <div class="wrapimg">
                    <a href="<?php echo $contenido_link; ?>"><img alt="Image de <?php echo $contenido_titulo; ?>" src="<?php echo $contenido_imagen; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you tell how's it's better?

Comment: why to use multiple `<?php  ?>` if it can done through only one. please specify why it's better. otherwise don't say that this is better.

Comment: Because you don have to modify the HTML from " to '